# ios 8 UILocalNotification missed, only sound

Tags: ios8, uilocalnotification

I schedule local notification in the app like this:

```
UILocalNotification * notification = [UILocalNotification new];
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
notification.fireDate = date;
notification.timeZone = DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE;
notification.alertBody = alertBody;
notification.alertAction = @"View";
notification.soundName = @"my_sound";
notification.userInfo = userInfoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

On the latest version of the ios 8 gm something broken, I can hear sound from the notification, but there is no alert, no messages in the notification сentre and so on.
I added to the

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions:

   ....
   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

    //ios 8
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:

                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                         categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
```

But there is no alert for the user to request permissions on a first run.